# How to modify the path bash: /home/joydev/home/joydev/root/root-6.28.04-install/bin/thisroot.sh: No such file or directory

Tags: command-line, bash, bashrc

could you please clarify how to solve the following problem?

Whenever I am opening the terminal I am getting following message:

```
bash: /home/joydev/home/joydev/root/root-6.28.04-install/bin/thisroot.sh: No such file or directory
```

The relevant output part of `cat ~/.bashrc` is:

```
. ~/home/joydev/root/root-6.28.04-install/bin/thisroot.sh
. ~/root/root-6.28.04-install/bin/thisroot.sh
. ~/root/root-6.28.04-install/bin/thisroot.sh
. ~/root/root-6.28.04-install/bin/thisroot.sh
. ~/root/root-6.28.04-install/bin/thisroot.sh
. ~/root/root-6.28.04/buildroot/bin/thisroot.sh
. ~/root/root-6.28.04/buildroot/bin/thisroot.sh
```

Comment: You should have added the directory to `$PATH`: `/home/joydev/home/joydev/root/root-6.28.04-install/bin`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add the output of `cat ~/.bashrc` ... The `thisroot.sh` file appears to be already called by full path so I guess `$PATH` is not the issue here but rather might be a none-existent file indeed as it appears @waltinator

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments. I am getting following 
l
. ~/home/joydev/root/root-6.28.04-install/bin/thisroot.sh

. ~/root/root-6.28.04-install/bin/thisroot.sh

. ~/root/root-6.28.04-install/bin/thisroot.sh

. ~/root/root-6.28.04-install/bin/thisroot.sh

. ~/root/root-6.28.04-install/bin/thisroot.sh

. ~/root/root-6.28.04/buildroot/bin/thisroot.sh

. ~/root/root-6.28.04/buildroot/bin/thisroot.sh

Comment: Is this all the output of `cat ~/.bashrc`?

Comment: Those are the last few lines.

Comment: I solved the problem by removing the path from the  .bashrc

Answer (score 1):

`thisroot.sh` is apparently a script file sourced(*i.e. lines/commands in it are imported and executed*) with the `.`[(*period/dot*)](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-_002e) command in your [`.bashrc`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html)(*which in-turn is sourced every-time you open your terminal with `bash` as it's shell*) file ... The `source` command and its alias the dot `.` take a path after them which can be either full absolute/real i.e. starting from the root directory i.e. `/` like:

```
/home/joydev/root/root-6.28.04-install/bin/thisroot.sh
```

Or it can be "relative" to e.g. your home directory like:

```
~/root/root-6.28.04-install/bin/thisroot.sh
```

Where the tilde `~` will be expanded by your shell to the real path to your home directory i.e.:

```
$ echo ~
/home/joydev
```

Therefore, this line in your `.bashrc` file:

```
. ~/home/joydev/root/root-6.28.04-install/bin/thisroot.sh
```

will expand to:

```
. /home/joydev/home/joydev/root/root-6.28.04-install/bin/thisroot.sh
```

and `bash` will try to source a none-existent file path ... Hence, the error message you see:

```
bash: /home/joydev/home/joydev/root/root-6.28.04-install/bin/thisroot.sh: No such file or directory
```

Needless to say that if you fix that line by either removing `~` or removing its expansion `/home/joydev`, the error should disappear if that `thisroot.sh` file exists at the specified path ... Which appears to be the case as no errors printed from processing the other similar paths to the file in the following lines in your `.bashrc` file.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clear explanation @Raff